# Blazor @onclick not working once deployed

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm new to blazor.

@onclick is working on local development but once it is deployed it's not working anymore.

Even the counter page example is not working.

What we've tried:
adding these in _Imports.razor

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
```

and in Host.cshtml updated to this

```
<base href="/" />
```

writing console not working as well.

```
@onclick="@(e => Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!"))"
```

Comment: Examine the browser console, network log etc...

Comment: You'll need to give us more information to get a useful answer. What is the deployment environment? Have you tried deploying any other way, like a staging server? What have you done so far to debug the issue?

Comment: Hi @NikP, updated the question. we deployed it to our staging env and in azure. I can't debug our staging env as my local dev't is working fine.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes fetch are working but the onclick event is not

Comment: And of course `Console.WriteLine() won't work when deployed, that's not a good test-case.

Comment: No errors. I already disabled all my chrome extensions

Comment: You tagged the question as Blazor- Server, so assuming that, my first instinct is that the SignalR connection isn't setting up right but you are still getting the fetch somehow, and navigation COULD be going through page requests and not SignalR. You might compare the network traffic in your dev environment to deployment and see what it looks like for load, and then specifically check the WebSocket messages and click the button a few times. Every click should show both a WS up and down message, so that might help debug?

Comment: @NikP, you're right! I do received a message in socket on my local but not on the deployed env. do you have an idea why is it like that? I'll do ask our Backend guys for this.

Comment: I've seen a lot of questions on SO about it, and I seem to remember IIS was involved, but take that with a grain of salt. Your BE engineers would likely be the place to start.